# Uploading single and multiple files in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

i need help with this please.. the upload is working well with no error but it dosn't really upload anything.. as u can see i used multer.. i guess it's not calling data cause whene i consol.log data it shows nothing .. i will appreciate any help

file uploader :

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toast} from 'react-toastify';
import ('./Uploader.css');

export const FileUploader = ({onSuccess}) => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const onInputChange = (e) => { 
        setFiles(e.target.files)
    };

    const onSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();

        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('file', files[i]);
        }

        axios.post('//localhost:4000/filesAPI/upload', data)
            .then((response) => {
                toast.success('Upload Success');
                onSuccess(response.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                toast.error('Upload Error')
            })
    };

    
    return (
        <form method="post" action="#" id="#" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group files">
                <label>Upload Your File </label>
                <input type="file" className="form-control" onChange={onInputChange} multiple/>         
            </div>

            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
};
```

app.js client side :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Preview } from './component/Preview/Preview';
import { FileUploader } from './component/FileUploader/FileUploader';

import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
    const onSuccess = (savedFiles) => {
        setFiles(savedFiles)
    };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FileUploader onSuccess={onSuccess}/>
      <Preview files={files}/>
      <ToastContainer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

app.js server side :

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()
const connectDB = require('./config/connectDB');
connectDB()
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
 

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/filesAPI', require('./Routes/FilesRoutes'))

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "myUploads")
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage}).array('files');

app.post('/filesAPI/upload', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err)
        }
        else{
        return res.status(200).send(req.files)
    }})
});

var port = process.env.PORT || '4000'
app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err)
        throw err
    console.log('Server is running on port', port)
})
```

i make reaserches on google and youtube and i found nothing please help

Answer (score 0):

there is one main issue in your `for loop` in onSubmit of FileUploader.js . You are using `data.append('file', files[i])` but on your server side, you are getting it using files as `multer({storage}).array('files')`. So you need to make the same, you can change this `data.append("files", files[i])`.

Other than this while calling Axios, you need to use the complete URL as `http://localhost:4000/filesAPI/upload`.

For a step to step guide, using multi with react and node js, you can use this [link](https://www.positronx.io/react-file-upload-tutorial-with-node-express-and-multer/). This is a pretty good explanation.